# Execute headless chrome browser in Linux machine using Robot framework

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I am executing my scripts in the Jenkins pipeline which is available in a Linux machine. I am trying with Chrome options and I add chrome driver for Linux only. I am getting the below error.

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Please find the below code for your reference.

```
${result} =    Replace String    ${EXECDIR}     //       \\
log     ${result}

${chrome_path}      Catenate   SEPARATOR=      ${result}        /      Linux    /   chromedriver
log     ${chrome_path}
${options}  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
#Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --headless
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --disable-gpu
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']

${preferences} =    Create Dictionary   setAcceptUntrustedCertificates=True    setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer=True
Create WebDriver  Chrome   chrome_options=${options}   desired_capabilities=${preferences}      executable_path=${chrome_path}
Set Window Size     ${1400}     ${600}
Maximize Browser Window
sleep    3s
Go to     ${URL}
```

Comment: Since you are sending path's for the binary I would say that you are already trying to fix something and are having permission issues with the Jenkins user not being able to access the chrome binary.
I would first login with the Jenkins user and check if chrome binary is on path variable

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it can't find the chrome binary (*chrome*, not *chromedriver*). You can fix this by setting the `binary_location` option:

```
${options.binary_location}=  Set variable  /the/path/to/chrome
```